# Can anybody help me woth this javascript console.log question I have?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, console.log

I am trying to get through this coding puzzle. I just wanted to know if anybody could tell me why in my `console.log` gives me the whole function instead of only the returned answer.

```
function basketballPlayers(fouls) {
    if (fouls == 5) {
      return "4 players"
      } else if(fouls <= 5)
      return "5 players"
  }
```

I want to say 5 `fouls` equal 4 `players` lesser than 5 `fouls` equal 4 `players`.
Im a newbie so dont mind my simple code

Comment: `why in my code console.log` ... your code doesn't have a console.log ... are you doing `console.log(basketballPlayers)` because that will show the function ... you'd need something like `console.log(basketballPlayers(3))`

Comment: Apart of your question, note that the "else if" part shouldn't use <= but <. The case where fouls equals 5 has already been covered in your if. Also think of what's going to happen if you would call your function with fouls equals to 6. You're going to tell me it's not intended to be called that way, but it would still be good practice to cover that case.

Answer (score 2):

Just doing something like

```
console.log(basketballPlayers);
```

is going to literally console log the function. You need to **call** the function, which is done with a pair of brackets (). This function also takes a parameter, so that must be entered into the brackets as well:

```
console.log(basketballPlayers(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```js
function basketballPlayers(fouls) {
  if (fouls == 5)
    return "4 players"
  else if (fouls < 5)
    return "5 players"
}
console.log(basketballPlayers(3))

console.log(basketballPlayers(5))
```

Comment: In second condition there's no need of `=` again. Since it's already been covered as part of first condition.